# Clip SVG image with rectangle boundaries when it is resized in D3

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg, interact.js

In this [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Pgschr/v2a5tgoz/22/) I combine `D3` with `interact.js`, both working on `SVG`. There's a group that contains a rect and an image. The group class is resizable and that works fine. The problem is that the rect, when resized, should clip the image (i.e. the image should never be out of the rectangle borders) but it does not. I use a D3 `clipPath` for that, but it's not working. What is the problem?

```
var svg = d3.select("body")
            .append("svg")
            .attr("width", 500)
            .attr("height", 200);

var g = svg.append('g')
           .attr('class', 'resize-me');

var rect = g.append('rect')
    .attr('stroke', 'blue')
    .attr('x', 0)
    .attr('y', 0)
    .attr("width", 200)
    .attr("height", 200)
    .attr('stroke-width', 2)
    .attr('stroke', 'white')
    .attr('fill', 'grey');

var image = g.append('image')
      .attr('x', 0)
      .attr('y', 0)
      .attr('width', 128)
      .attr('height', 128)
      .attr("xlink:href", imageUrl);


interact('.resize-me')
    .resizable({
        edges: { left: true, right: true, bottom: true, top: true }
    })
    .on('resizemove', function(event) {

        var target = event.target;
        var rect = target.childNodes[0];
        var img = target.childNodes[1];

        var x = (parseFloat(target.getAttribute('endx')) || 0)
        var y = (parseFloat(target.getAttribute('endy')) || 0)

        rect.setAttribute('width', event.rect.width);
        rect.setAttribute('height', event.rect.height);

        x += event.deltaRect.left
        y += event.deltaRect.top
        rect.setAttribute('transform', 'translate(' + x + ', ' + y + ')')

        rect.setAttribute('endx', x)
        rect.setAttribute('endy', y)


        // clip image

        svg.append('defs')
           .append('clipPath')
           .attr('id', 'clip2')
           .append('rect')
           .attr('x', 0)
           .attr('y', 0)
           .attr('width', event.rect.width)
           .attr('height', event.rect.height);

        image.attr("clip-path", "url(#clip2)");

    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you want the image to always expand to fill the grey box? https://jsfiddle.net/alexander_L/u607w315/12/ (version 12 for image expanding)

[image]

Also, you are appending `<def/>` tags every time the event fires:

[image]

It gets quickly out of hand.

You should either attach the `<def/>` to some dummy one element array data and use the d3.js update pattern or simpler you could just create the `<def/>` tag in your source code and update the attribute of that same tag each time.

You can do it once at the start:

```
var def = svg.append('defs')
           .append('clipPath')
           .attr('id', 'clip2')
           .append('rect')
           .attr('x', 0)
           .attr('y', 0)
           .attr('width', 200)
           .attr('height', 200);
```

And then use this variable and update during your event:

```
def.attr('x', 0)
           .attr('y', 0)
           .attr('width', event.rect.width)
           .attr('height', event.rect.height);
```

Then you avoid this issue.

https://jsfiddle.net/alexander_L/u607w315/11/ (version 11 for image clipping)

Do you want this behaviour:

[image]

The image is clipped when the grey box is smaller in one dimension than the image?

**UPDATE**

Since the OP noticed a bug in the original code which causes the grey box to always snap back to at least the height or width of the image, I tried to also solve this problem.

However, I also noticed some odd behaviour, that the top left corner of the box could not be extended further up or left so I fixed that first: https://jsfiddle.net/alexander_L/u607w315/25/

See the .gif of the new behaviour and the old bug the OP mentioned:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I don't want the image to expand, I want it to be clipped, so your second answer works, although I found a detail, if you first move up the bottom border until the middle of the picture, then move left the right border, the bottom border will move by itself to the bottom of the picture

Comment: Can you show me a screenshot of what you are describing? I don't see that behaviour here - https://jsfiddle.net/alexander_L/u607w315/16/ and please let me know what the desired behaviour is exactly. Screenshots would also be helpful.

Comment: Ahh, maybe I understand what you mean now. That's how you set it up in your code? I only fixed the clip-path part of your code. See - https://jsfiddle.net/alexander_L/u607w315/19/ and notice the behaviour also that occurs when you drag the top left corner etc. if you want me to fix this also, please modify your question to include that.

Comment: look at [this](https://1drv.ms/v/s!Au4Vkx6gmEf-iRWZgbhS04BS718m?e=WqNap7) the bottom border goes up by itself

Comment: yes, you are right, that behavior was already in the question

Comment: I tried to also fix the top left behaviour I mentioned - https://i.stack.imgur.com/62Kmw.gif and started to think of the fix to that and the other bug originally in the question that we are discussing here - https://jsfiddle.net/alexander_L/u607w315/26/

Comment: Alex, please take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60973085/making-interact-js-resizable-pixel-perfect)

Comment: Will try to take a look later/tomorrow :)