# Making interact.js resizable pixel perfect

Tags: javascript, svg, interact.js

In this [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Pgschr/s5bv1noe/7/) I have an SVG rect that is resizable using `interact.js`. There's also a 10px by 10px grid and the `.resizable` function has included a 10px by 10 px snap. The objective is to resize the rect and have the edges snap exactly on the grid.

In most cases it works fine, but many times it is not, as you can see in the picture below. Maybe an adjustment needs to be done manually on `resizeend` ? How to fix this problem?

[image]

Comment: Probably not the most elegant solution, but what about, since it seems to be a grid with squares of 10 pixels, recalculate the values by rounding them to the nearest ten on resize `target.setAttribute(a, Math.round(v/10)*10);` ? I just tried it on your fiddle link and it seems to work out. Perhaps there is a small bug in `interact.js`, which you could fix by rounding the numbers if they are not a multiple of ten.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Erik said:

With this `target.setAttribute(attr/a, Math.round(v/10)*10)` it seems to work:

```
  .on('resizemove', function(event) {
    // Resize the rect, not the group, it will resize automatically
    const target = event.target.querySelector('rect');

    for (const attr of ['width', 'height']) {
      let v = Number(target.getAttribute(attr));
      v += event.deltaRect[attr];
      target.setAttribute(attr, Math.round(v/10)*10);
    }

    for (const attr of ['top', 'left']) {
      const a = attr == 'left' ? 'x' : 'y';
      let v = Number(target.getAttribute(a));
      v += event.deltaRect[attr];
      target.setAttribute(a, Math.round(v/10)*10);
    }

    findLocations(rect, handles);
  });
```

Full Demo here - https://jsfiddle.net/alexander_L/1mzs36qL/3/ and below:

```js
const svg = document.getElementById('mysvg');
const rect = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "rect");
const group = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "g");


// draw vertical lines
var gridSize = 10;
for (var i=0;i < 100;i++){
  var line = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "line");    
  svg.appendChild(line);
  line.setAttribute("x1", (i + 1) * gridSize)
  line.setAttribute("y1", 0)
  line.setAttribute("x2", (i + 1) * gridSize)
  line.setAttribute("y2", 500)
  line.setAttribute("stroke-width", 1)
  line.setAttribute("stroke", 'gray');
}
        
// draw horizontal lines
for (var i=0;i < 100;i++){
  var line = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "line");    
  svg.appendChild(line);
  line.setAttribute("x1", 0)
  line.setAttribute("y1", (i + 1) * gridSize)
  line.setAttribute("x2", 2000)
  line.setAttribute("y2", (i + 1) * gridSize)
  line.setAttribute("stroke-width", 1)
  line.setAttribute("stroke", 'gray');
}


svg.appendChild(group);
group.appendChild(rect);
group.setAttribute('class', 'resize-me');

rect.setAttribute('x', 100);
rect.setAttribute('y', 100);
rect.setAttribute('width', 100);
rect.setAttribute('height', 100);
rect.setAttribute('stroke-width', 1);
rect.setAttribute('stroke', 'white');
rect.setAttribute('fill', 'grey');

// Create the handles
const handles = [];
for (let i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
  const handle = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "rect");

  handle.setAttribute('width', 8);
  handle.setAttribute('height', 8);
  handle.setAttribute('stroke-width', 1);
  handle.setAttribute('stroke', 'white');
  handle.setAttribute('fill', 'black');

  handles.push(handle);
  group.appendChild(handle);
}

// Manually assign them their resize duties (R->L, T->B)
handles[0].classList.add('resize-top', 'resize-left');
handles[1].classList.add('resize-top');
handles[2].classList.add('resize-top', 'resize-right');
handles[3].classList.add('resize-left');
handles[4].classList.add('resize-right');
handles[5].classList.add('resize-bottom', 'resize-left');
handles[6].classList.add('resize-bottom');
handles[7].classList.add('resize-bottom', 'resize-right');



// This function takes the rect and the list of handles and positions
// the handles accordingly
const findLocations = (r, h) => {
  const x = Number(r.getAttribute('x'));
  const y = Number(r.getAttribute('y'));
  const width = Number(r.getAttribute('width'));
  const height = Number(r.getAttribute('height'));

  // Important these are in the same order as the classes above
  let locations = [
    [0, 0],
    [width / 2, 0],
    [width, 0],
    [0, height / 2],
    [width, height / 2],
    [0, height],
    [width / 2, height],
    [width, height]
  ];

  // Move each location such that it's relative to the (x,y) of the rect,
  // and also subtract half the width of the handles to make up for their
  // own size.
  locations = locations.map(subarr => [
    subarr[0] + x - 4,
    subarr[1] + y - 4
  ]);

  for (let i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
    h[i].setAttribute('x', locations[i][0]);
    h[i].setAttribute('y', locations[i][1]);
  }
}

interact('.resize-me')
  .resizable({
    edges: {
      left: '.resize-left',
      right: '.resize-right',
      bottom: '.resize-bottom',
      top: '.resize-top'
    },
    modifiers: [
      interact.modifiers.snap({
          targets: [
            interact.snappers.grid({
              x: 10,
              y: 10,
            })
          ]
        })
     ]
  })
  .on('resizemove', function(event) {
    // Resize the rect, not the group, it will resize automatically
    const target = event.target.querySelector('rect');

    for (const attr of ['width', 'height']) {
      let v = Number(target.getAttribute(attr));
      v += event.deltaRect[attr];
      target.setAttribute(attr, Math.round(v/10)*10);
    }

    for (const attr of ['top', 'left']) {
      const a = attr == 'left' ? 'x' : 'y';
      let v = Number(target.getAttribute(a));
      v += event.deltaRect[attr];
      target.setAttribute(a, Math.round(v/10)*10);
    }

    findLocations(rect, handles);
  });

findLocations(rect, handles);
```

```css
svg {
  width: 100%;
  height: 240px;
  background-color: #2e9;
  
  -ms-touch-action: none;
      touch-action: none;
}
body { margin: 0; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/interactjs@latest/dist/interact.min.js"></script>

<svg id="mysvg"></svg>
```

Comment: Alex, I found a problem. If the rect x is 95 `rect.setAttribute('x', 95);` when you move the left side to snap the grid, the rect expands its width also on the right side. The right side should not move.

Comment: Ok, I'll take a look and try to fix it.